# How to make a binary cross validation table from a pivot table using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot, mask

I have a dataset looking like below

[image: before pivot]

When I do pivot, then it should look like this

[image: after pivot]

But what I truely want is this

[image: what I want pivot]

I can do it with loops and stuffs in kinda-manual way which is not pretty and intuitive... like I could search values that are not None type then replace by True and ifnot False. But this is not, again, pretty and it could take some time if I execute it on a large dataset (which will be the case).

So I would like to know if I could do it with a single line or a couple of lines in a prettier and faster way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
ID,ISIN
AXAMIL,A
AXAMIL,B
AXAMIL,C
AXAEXL,D
UNPEVL,A
UNPEVL,E
UNPMSP,A
UNPMSP,B"""), sep=',')
df
```

We can use a `groupby`, then `unstack` the result and convert it as `boolean` to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df.groupby(['ID', 'ISIN']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).astype(bool).rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
    ID      A       B       C       D       E
0   AXAEXL  False   False   False   True    False
1   AXAMIL  True    True    True    False   False
2   UNPEVL  True    False   False   False   True
3   UNPMSP  True    True    False   False   False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `isna()` method, like so:

```
new_df = ~df.isna()
```

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table` is what you're looking for.
`assign` just creates dummy variable for aggregation.

```py
df = (
    df.assign(**{"": 1})
      .pivot_table(
          index="ID", 
          columns="ISIN", 
          aggfunc="max", 
          fill_value=0,
      ).astype(bool)
)
```

Outputs:

```py
ISIN        A      B      C      D      E
ID
AXAEXL  False  False  False   True  False
AXAMIL   True   True   True  False  False
UNPEVL   True  False  False  False   True
UNPMSP   True   True  False  False  False
```